# How can I identify number of spans with a minimum N samples in between?

Tags: matlab, count, signal-processing

On Matlab, I have a piece of code counting the number of spans above a certain threshold, in a biomedical signal:

```
   EMG_signal = [1 2 4 2 0 0 2 2 0 2 0 2 2 2] % Sample signal with 2 bursts
   threshold = 1.5
   above_threshold = (EMG_signal > threshold)
   minAcceptableLength = 3; % or 200 or whatever.
   % Find spans that are long enough.
   isLongEnough = bwareafilt(above_threshold, [minAcceptableLength, inf])
   % Count the number of spans (bursts) that are long enough.
   [labeledSpans, numberOfBursts] = bwlabel(isLongEnough)
```

I am interested in adding a further condition to the number of spants count: a span should be identified not only when greater than above_threshold and for a minAcceptableLength, but also when there is a minimum of N samples between two different spans (otherwise it should be counted as 1 span).

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some morphological operations to determine if two spans are `N` or more samples apart. The idea is to "dilate" each span of 1's by `N` samples which will theoretically merge two spans which are closer than `N` samples apart. You can then follow this up with an erosion of the same number of samples which will shrink all spans by back to their original size except that the merged spans will remain merged.

In the Image Processing Toolbox, this methodology is provided with [`imclose`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclose.html)

```
values = [1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1];

N = 3;      % Breaks between span < 3 will be removed

kernel = repmat(1, 1, N);

result = imclose(values, kernel);
%   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

For your specific problem, you can apply these functions to `isLongEnough` to merge spans prior to calling `bwlabel`.

Comment: What if a span is not long enough at first, but after merging spans they become long enough (they would then be counted as spans)? How could avoid that situation?

Comment: @AJMA You could perform the above procedure on `above_threshold` instead of `isLongEnough`